# Continual Integration with Hudson and Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, continuous-integration, hudson

I am trying to figure out the best way to set our new process and would love to get some feedback:

We are using Mercurial and Hudson for CI purposes.
I am leading a team with several developers.

Now, when tickets come in, I assign them to their appropriate developers who check out trunk and make their changes.

I have my directory structure as follows:

```
PROJECT/bugfixes
```

Now, my developers currently clone their fixes to PROJECT/bugfixes/bugticket (this is a clone of PROJECT with the appropriate changes)

At the end of the week, I can look in bugfixes and see several bugtickets directory and I would like to merge some of the them (I choose which ones I want) into a release build:

```
PROJECT/releasebuild
```

I clone PROJECT into releasebuild and I pull down the bugtickets I want and merge them in.

I started playing with Hudson and I think it will serve my purposes better.

So now, my questions:

- How can I set up Hudson to perform the above task?  I think my developers should use branches rather than the directory of PROJECT/bugfixes/bugtickets.  Is this correct?
- For each branch I want to import, should I create a new Hudson project for that particular branch?  It looks like the Mercurial plugin for Hudson only accepts one branch.

Is there a better way I should do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to set up a hudson job per-branch. On a previous project, I actually found it was easier not to use the hudson mercurial plugin. Instead, I set up a project (for the default branch only) which did a `hg purge` (to remove any artifacts that were not part of the repository) then a `hg pull` (from the master repo) followed by `hg update default`. Then it did the build.

I set up a mercurial hook in the repository that triggered a hudson build using the hudson CLI any time that one or more changesets were committed to the repository.

Of course, things may have changed since then - I haven't looked at the hudson/hg integration for about 2 years.

Here's the hook I used - it should be fairly simple to update it to the latest version of hudson or jenkins, or to handle multiple branches.

```
"""
[hooks]
commit.hudson = python:(path to)/hudson.py:hudson_build_trigger
changegroup.hudson = python:(path to)/hudson.py:hudson_build_trigger
"""

from mercurial.i18n import _
from mercurial import localrepo, util, commands, cmdutil, extensions
from mercurial.context import changectx
from mercurial.node import nullrev
import os, os.path, subprocess

def extsetup(ui):
    pass

def hudson_build_trigger(ui, repo, node, **kwargs):
    """Triggers a hudson build. Uses a [hudson] section in hgrc. The 'jar', 'url'
    and 'job' parameters are required, the 'branch' parameter defaults to 'default'
    if not specified e.g.

    [hudson]
    jar = /path/to/hudson-cli.jar
    url = http://server:port/path/to/hudson
    job = hudson_mercurial_job
    branch = developer1

    Use as a commit and changegroup hook e.g.:

    [hooks]
    commit.hudson = python:(path to)/hudson.py:hudson_build_trigger
    changegroup.hudson = python:(path to)/hudson.py:hudson_build_trigger
    """

    jar = ui.config('hudson', 'jar', '')
    url = ui.config('hudson', 'url', '')
    job = ui.config('hudson', 'job', '')
    branch = ui.config('hudson', 'branch', 'default')

    if not jar or not os.path.exists(jar) or not url or not job:
        raise util.Abort(_('must specify Hudson CLI jar, URL and job'))

    ctx = repo[node]

    for rev in range(ctx.rev(), len(repo)):
        if repo[rev].branch() == branch:
            # Trigger a hudson build
            result = subprocess.call([
                'java',
                '-jar',
                jar,
                '-s',
                url,
                'build',
                job
            ])

            if result != 0:
                raise util.Abort(_('failed to trigger Hudson build'))

            ui.write(_("triggered build for %s\n" % (job,)))
            break
```